# How to increase the request timeout of Lambda function while running the lambda function locally?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have created a lambda function. Here is the code:

```
exports.handler = async event => {
    if(event.method ==='GET')
    {
        const sql = require('mssql');
        const config = {
                            user: username,
                            password: password,
                            server: server,
                            database: database,
                             options: {
                                        encrypt: true
                                      }
                    }
         try {
            // Open DB Connection
            let pool = await sql.connect(config)

            // Query Database
            let result = await pool.request()
                .query('select * from account')

            // Close DB Connection
            pool.close();

            // The results of our query
            console.log("Results:", result);

            return {
                statusCode:200,
                body:JSON.stringify(result)
            }

        } catch (err) {
            // Error running our SQL Query
            console.error("ERROR: Exception thrown running SQL", err);
        }

        return {
                statusCode:200,
                body:'Nothing to load'
            }
    }
    else
        return {statusCode:405};
};
```

I have a couple of questions related to this lambda function. I'm listing here:

1. How to call async lambda function locally? I have run sync lambda function locally with success.
2. When uploading the lambda function on AWS, I got the request timeout issue. I fixed this issue by increasing the timeout on AWS console. How can I increase the request timeout of the lambda function locally from 3 seconds to 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using serverless you can set a `timeout: 30000` parameter in the serverless.yml

you can a serverless function locally

```
serverless invoke local --stage staging -f functionName -p testData/event.json
```

Comment: how are you running the function locally

Comment: I'm using lambda local running lambda local. Here is the command:
lambda-local -l index.js -h handler -e handler.js

Answer (score 0):

1. How to call async lambda function locally? I have run sync lambda function locally with success.

> From AWS documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html) your function should work as long as you're using Node 8.10 or higher version:

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return await lambda.getAccountSettings().promise() ;
};
```

2. When uploading the lambda function on AWS, I got the request timeout issue. I fixed this issue by increasing the timeout on AWS console. How can I increase the request timeout of the lambda function locally from 3 seconds to 10 seconds?

> you can see the answer to that in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) that lambda has a default timeout of 15 minutes. If you were referring to the connection of mysql you can see in [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) that both requestTimeout and connectionTimeout have default value of 15 seconds.